# Twitter login with Spring Social not working

Tags: spring, twitter, spring-security, spring-social

I have a working Spring Boot app using Oauth2 authentication (password grant type). I now need to support Facebook and Twitter login.

I am using a custom TokenGranter to allow a client to send me a Facebook access token or Twitter consumer id and secret so they can be logged into my server application and receive an OAuth2 access_token I generate. I have this working for Facebook using `FacebookConnectionFactory`:

```
Connection<Facebook> connection = facebookConnectionFactory.createConnection(new AccessGrant(providerToken));
```

With the connection, I get the user id of Facebook:

```
String providerUserId = connection.getKey().getProviderUserId();
```

With this id, I search if there is such a user in my `UserRepository` and if so, I log in the user:

```
CustomUserDetails userDetails = new CustomUserDetails(user);
userAuth = new SocialAuthenticationToken(connection, userDetails,
                                                 null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(userAuth);
```

This all works fine. Doing the same with Twitter:

```
Connection<Twitter> connection = twitterConnectionFactory.createConnection(new OAuthToken(providerToken, tokenSecret));
```

Gives me this exception:

```
Unable to connect with Twitter: Authorization is required for the operation, 
but the API binding was created without authorization.
```

What I find strange is that using `TwitterTemplate` with the same app id and secret and consumer and consumer secret does work.

```
TwitterTemplate twitterTemplate = new TwitterTemplate(...);
UserOperations userOperations = twitterTemplate.userOperations();
AccountSettings accountSettings = userOperations.getAccountSettings();
```

I need the `Connection<Twitter>` object for the `SocialAuthenticationToken`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Stupid mistake, I had:

```
@Value("spring.social.twitter.app-id")
private String twitterAppId;
@Value("spring.social.twitter.app-secret")
private String twitterAppSecret;
```

in stead of:

```
@Value("${spring.social.twitter.app-id}")
private String twitterAppId;
@Value("${spring.social.twitter.app-secret}")
private String twitterAppSecret;
```

So I put the literal text `spring.social.twitter.app-id` instead of the value of the property.